# Traefik 2: access to .well-known acme folder, What do you think?

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, traefik, lets-encrypt

I had problem with my mailserver is it was not working properly when i added mailbox to Outlook. It warned me that i use wrong certificate, on closer inspection it showed default email docker creator certificate. Even though webmail is protected with SSL from Traefik.
After researching I manage to come up with this, it is combination of ones guy docker compose, cannot find the link for his post. And my previous attempt to host acme challenge on my flask website, what was overwritten by default with Nginx Proxy manager, so I abandon it.
But now while working with Traefik, what provides much more flexibility i was able to do it:

This is one page on my flask website, what returns files from within the .well-known folder, which is mapped in each docker container what needs access to lets encrypt certification process, behind reverse proxy.

```
@app.route('/.well-known/acme-challenge/<acmechalleng>')
def acme(acmechalleng):
    try:
        # acme_folder is file path to folder where challenges are stored
        # for example: acmechall_folder = os.path.abspath('acmefiles/')
        acme_folder=config.acmechall_folder
        extr = {}
        # Sets up ignored file names what will not be showed
        ignore_files='.paths.json'
        try:
            items = json.load(open(os.path.join(acme_folder, '.paths.json')))
        except Exception:
            items = ""

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(acme_folder):
            for f in files:
                # this filters files we do not want to show ie: paths file
                if f not in ignore_files:
                    full_path = os.path.join(root, f)
                    path = full_path.split(acme_folder,1)[1]
                    path = path.replace("\\", "/")
                    split_path = path.split('/')
                    extr.update({path[1:]: 0})
        if items != extr:
            with open(os.path.join(acme_folder, '.paths.json'), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                json.dump(extr, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        # Only files what are in .pahts.json will be allowed to be read
        items = json.load(open(os.path.join(acme_folder, '.paths.json')))
        existing = []
        for key, arr in items.items():
            existing.append(key)

        if acmechalleng in existing:
            with open(os.path.join(acme_folder, acmechalleng),"rb") as f:
                content = f.readlines()
            return Response(content)
        else:
            return render_template('404.html', **_auto_values), 404        
    except Exception as err:
        return render_template('404.html', **_auto_values), 404
```

Poste.io mail server Docker File, with access to .well-known challenges for Letsencrypt

```
version: '3'
networks:
  traefikauth_net:
    external: true
services:
  mailserver:
    image: analogic/poste.io
    container_name: mailserver
    hostname: mail.mydomain.com
    networks:
      - traefikauth_net
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "25:25"
      - "587:587"
      - "993:993"
    environment:                                                                                                                                                                                         
      - HOSTNAME=poste.mydomain.com
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=admin@mydomain.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=mydomain.com
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=poste.mydomain.com
      - HTTPS=OFF
      - DISABLE_CLAMAV=TRUE
      - DISABLE_RSPAMD=TRUE
    volumes:
      - /opt/traefik/.well-known:/opt/www/.well-known/acme-challenge
      - /opt/mailserver:/data
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.poste-letsencrypt.rule=HostRegexp(`mydomain.com`,`{subdomain:[a-z]*}.mydomain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/.well-known/`)" 
      - "traefik.http.routers.poste-letsencrypt.entrypoints=http"                                                                                                                                          
      - "traefik.http.routers.poste-letsencrypt.service=mail"                                                                                                                                           
      - "traefik.http.services.poste-letsencrypt.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mail.rule=Host(`poste.mydomain.com`)"                                                                                                                                   
      - "traefik.http.routers.mail.entrypoints=https"                                                                                                                                                     
      - "traefik.http.routers.mail.tls.certresolver=cloudflare"                                                                                                                                       
      - "traefik.http.routers.mail.service=mail"                                                                                                                                                       
      - "traefik.http.services.mail.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
```

The main website, on "mydomain.com" needs also Traefik labels:

```
volumes:
  - /opt/traefik/.well-known:/var/www/wellknown
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.flask-letsencrypt.entrypoints=http"
  - "traefik.http.routers.flask-letsencrypt.rule=HostRegexp(`mydomain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/.well-known/`)"
  - "traefik.http.services.flask-letsencrypt.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
  - "traefik.http.routers.flask-letsencrypt.service=myflask"
  - "traefik.http.routers.myflask.entrypoints=https"
  - "traefik.http.routers.myflask.rule=Host(`mydomain.com`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.myflask.service=myflask"
  - "traefik.http.routers.myflask.tls=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.myflask.tls.certresolver=cloudflare"
  - "traefik.http.services.myflask.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
```

I also have normal CertResolver for all the other domains what is in main Traefik file as follow traefik.yml:

```
certificatesResolvers:
  cloudflare:
    acme:
      email: admin@mydomain.com
      storage: /letsencrypt/acme.json
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: cloudflare
        resolvers:
          - "1.1.1.1:53"
          - "1.0.0.1:53"
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"
```

Traefik 2 docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /opt/traefik/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - /opt/traefik/conf:/additionalsettings
      - /opt/traefik/folderacme:/letsencrypt
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.mydomain.com`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=https'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=authelia@docker'
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.tls.certresolver=cloudflare"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.tls.domains[0].main=mydomain.com"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.tls.domains[0].sans=*.mydomain.com"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.authelia.forwardauth.address=http://authelia:9091/api/verify?rd=https://logmein.mydomain.com/"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.authelia.forwardauth.trustforwardheader=true"
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.authelia.forwardauth.authResponseHeaders=Remote-User, Remote-Groups, Remote-Name, Remote-Email'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.authelia-basic.forwardauth.address=http://authelia:9091/api/verify?auth=basic'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.authelia-basic.forwardauth.trustForwardHeader=true'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.authelia-basic.forwardauth.authResponseHeaders=Remote-User, Remote-Groups, Remote-Name, Remote-Email'
      # global redirect to https
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
      # middleware redirect
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"

    environment:    
      - CF_API_EMAIL=<cloudflare api email>
      - CF_API_KEY=<cloudflare api key for certresolver>
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    command:
      - '--api'
      - '--providers.docker=true'
      - '--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false'
      - '--entrypoints.http=true'
      - '--entrypoints.http.address=:80'
      - '--entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=https'
      - '--entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https'
      - '--entrypoints.https=true'
      - '--entrypoints.https.address=:443'
```

What do you think? I believe that python code could be much smaller, especially that part what stores the path in Json but i use that from my other project, and there I needed more then path to the file. This way I believe nobody should be able access other files, only those in ACME folder.

Comment: There is a hack to bypass the default acme-http@internal router: see this comment for the solution : https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/8992#issuecomment-1250394919